# TCP messages - Durable and fast solution tips?

Tags: sockets, spring-integration

We use Spring integration for TCP socket communication with the hardware.
The client would be sending a sequence number to uniquely identify a message. 
My requirement is to store these sequence numbers part of the socket message and validate them for non repetitive sequence numbers. 
I went thru IdempotentReceiver, sounds like what i wanted. 
But I need a durable and faster mechanism to store it, before unexpected shutdown of service and use the in memory cache for retrieving the latest sequence number.

Thank you in advance.!

Comment: This question is not about Programming!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore` for idempotent receiver:

> The `PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore` is backed by a properties file and a `PropertiesPersister`.
>
> By default, it only persists the state when the application context is closed normally. It implements `Flushable` so you can persist the state at will, be invoking `flush()`.

See more in its JavaDocs.

Comment: I would suggest something more robust for an application like this, such as the `RedisMetadataStore`. The properties store will slow down over time, since the whole in-memory map is written out on each flush.

Comment: Thank you Artem and Gary for your suggestions. Do you have an example for PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore? 
Also, do you think using HazelCast could help with the caching?